# What is a faithful representation of a Riemann surface?

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions, riemann-surfaces

The graph of a multivalued function on $\mathbb{C}$, such as $\log(z)$, is a surface in 4 dimensions. We can visualize it by plotting its real and imaginary parts, as done [here](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/visualizations/10/). This link says that the imaginary part is a "faithful representation" of $\log(z)$.

What is a faithful representation of a Riemann surface?

(A cursory google search turns up no results.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a standard term at all.  It appears that it is just intended to mean that the graph of the imaginary part is naturally in bijection with (or more strongly, diffeomorphic to) the Riemann surface of $\log(z)$.  In other words, the projection from the 4-dimensional plot of $\log(z)$ down to the 3-dimensional plot of just its imaginary part does not collapse any points together.

Comment: Okay. But it seems that the real part doesn't collapse any points together either. My question becomes: what is the standard "Riemann surface of $\log(z)$", or of any multivalued function for that matter? How do we pick between the real part and imaginary part?

Comment: The Riemann surface is the graph of _both_ parts together.  That is, it is the set of pairs $(z,w)\in\mathbb{C}^2$ such that $w$ is a value of $\log z$.

Comment: I see. Is this analogous to how the parabola $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y = x^2\}$ is diffeomorphic to its $x$-axis projection, but not its $y$-axis projection?

Comment: Yeah, it's the same idea.